# Regex to remove last char of capture group

Tags: regex

I have the follow text:

```
2017-08-28 08:44:12,2017-08-28 08:45:57,105.524,any,80,6415,13.2,458434,20.1,439004310,30.3,4344,33281855,957
```

and the follow regex:

```
^(?:[^\,]*\,){4}([^,]*)(80){1,5}([^\,]*\,){9}.*
```

I'm capturing the word `33281855,` as the 3rd group match. But I need this word without the comma, just like `33281855`.
How can I remove the comma?

Comment: Why don't you replace the comma.

Comment: No need to escape a comma.

Comment: @Wagner Did you have time to check my solution below?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix it is to unroll the `(a,){9}` into `a(?:,(a)){8}`:

```
^(?:[^,]*,){4}([^,]*)(80){1,5}[^,]*(?:,([^,]*)){8}.*
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZX0Y2/1)

Now, `[^,]*(?:,([^,]*)){8}` will match 0+ chars other than `,` (with `[^,]*`) and then exactly 8 occurrences of `,` and then 0+ chars other than `,` will be matched while capturing the non-`,` chunks into Group 2 (the last one will be returned with the match).

Note that a comma is not a special regex metacharacter and there is no need escaping it.

Comment: @Wagner Please accept the answer if it works for you.